# How to add a option to upload docx file to server

Tags: file-upload, server

I am building a website and i want to add an option for the user to upload the file and i will receive in my server and i tried some code on online but it didn't work but i need code

So , I Request anyone to help . I Appreciate Everyone who help me

Thank you
Neeraj

Comment: Please anyone Answer ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.